# First row empty when Importing data from CSV file to a database table of SQL Server using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When Importing data from CSV file to a SQL Server DB table, data will imported successfully with first row empty in the table.Not able to find the reason why first row is empty?

[image: CSV File]

[image: DB Table]

[image: Dataflow]

[image: FlatFileConnectionManager]

[image: DataTable]

Comment: The question as currently asked cannot be answered - too many possibilities. How have you defined your Flat File Connection Manager? What does your data look like? What does your data flow look like? How is your target table defined?

Comment: Modify my question and answered your question, please check

Comment: In the flat file connection manager, under preview, anything set for "Data rows to skip:" option?   and does your data show up there under preview?

Comment: How did you get that first screenshot?   Why are the column names on a different background color?   Can you post a screenshot of the text file open in notepad?

Comment: Tim Mylott, 'Data rows to skip' is set to 0.Data is showing up under preview.

Comment: Tab Alleman, I used notepad++ to open the CSV, that's why column names on a different background color.

Comment: if you have multiple rows do any of them load?  How about a screenshot of the data flow after it was successfully executed, prior to exiting debug, it should show number of rows between each item in the data flow.  Does that show 0 rows?

Comment: I have multiple rows and it's inserting all the rows in the table with first column blank.

Comment: that's different then what you originally posted. You were saying no row was getting inserted.   Now you're saying rows do get inserted, but the first column is blank.  Which one is it?  Also, you have to add @ in front of name if you want to notify an individual of a comment in SO.